# Problem changing default search engine in Firefox address bar

Tags: firefox

I have set the *keyword.URL* field in *about:config* to *https://www.google.co.in/search?q=* but still when I type anything in the address bar it shows results in Yahoo! search.

Comment: Do you have any add-ons installed?

Comment: Here's the screenshot of my add-on manager - https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-TyP4sP9s_fN1R3ZFEySF9nVEk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: How about you got to `about:support` then click the icon that says "Copy text to clipboard" then edit your question and add the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter *yahoo* in the search bar of *about:config* and check whether there is some value similar to the Yahoo search URL. Change this one to the Google search URL too.

BTW: This question doesn't seem to be related to Ubuntu

Comment: Here's the screen shot for the search result - https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-TyP4sP9s_fb0VpcUdDRlNTWU0/edit?usp=sharing
Sorry if I asked in the wrong section, I'm a newbie. Its just that I use Ubuntu, so I asked here.

Comment: Try changing *browser.search.selectedEngine*, *defaultEngineName* and *order.1* to *Google*